# Angular protractor tests: fdescribe (or fit) make chrome unreachable

Tags: angular, protractor, e2e-testing

Here some versions first:

```
Angular CLI: 6.0.8
Node: 8.10.0
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 6.0.5
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, language-service, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.6.8
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.6.8
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.6.8
@angular-devkit/core              0.6.8
@angular-devkit/schematics        0.6.8
@angular/cdk                      6.2.1
@angular/cli                      6.0.8
@angular/material                 6.2.1
@ngtools/webpack                  6.0.8
@schematics/angular               0.6.8
@schematics/update                0.6.8
rxjs                              6.2.1
typescript                        2.7.2
webpack                           4.8.3
```

Protractor, karma, jasmine:

```
"jasmine-core": "~2.8.0",
"jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
"karma": "~2.0.0",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
"karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
"karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
"karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
"protractor": "~5.1.2",
```

Chromedriver: `2.37`

as soon as I try to run a single test ('f' for focuse --> `fit('some test', () =>  { // ... });`), it makes my chrome unreachable:

```
(node:12700) [DEP0022] DeprecationWarning: os.tmpDir() is deprecated. Use os.tmpdir() instead.
[11:37:23] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[11:37:23] I/direct - Using ChromeDriver directly...
[11:38:26] E/launcher - chrome not reachable
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.37.544315 (730aa6a5fdba159ac9f4c1e8cbc59bf1b5ce12b7),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64)
[11:38:26] E/launcher - WebDriverError: chrome not reachable
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.37.544315 (730aa6a5fdba159ac9f4c1e8cbc59bf1b5ce12b7),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64)
    at Object.checkLegacyResponse (C:\Users\some.user\path-to-project\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\error.js:505:15)
    at parseHttpResponse (C:\Users\some.user\path-to-project\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\http.js:509:13)
    at doSend.then.response (C:\Users\some.user\path-to-project\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\http.js:440:13)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
From: Task: WebDriver.createSession()
    at Function.createSession (C:\Users\some.user\path-to-project\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver.js:777:24)
    at Function.createSession (C:\Users\some.user\path-to-project\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\chrome.js:709:29)
    at Direct.getNewDriver (C:\Users\some.user\path-to-project\node_modules\protractor\lib\driverProviders\direct.ts:90:25)
    at Runner.createBrowser (C:\Users\some.user\path-to-project\node_modules\protractor\lib\runner.ts:225:39)
    at q.then.then (C:\Users\some.user\path-to-project\node_modules\protractor\lib\runner.ts:391:27)
    at _fulfilled (C:\Users\some.user\path-to-project\node_modules\q\q.js:834:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (C:\Users\some.user\path-to-project\node_modules\q\q.js:863:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (C:\Users\some.user\path-to-project\node_modules\q\q.js:796:13)
    at C:\Users\some.user\path-to-project\node_modules\q\q.js:556:49
    at runSingle (C:\Users\some.user\path-to-project\node_modules\q\q.js:137:13)
[11:38:26] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 199
An unexpected error occured: undefined
```

In the task manager (under processes) I see a chrome instance running though (but not visible)...

Any thoughts?

Edit: Seems not entirely connected to `fit` / `fdescribe`, it seems in general very unstable... sometimes chrome starts, sometimes not (which makes me tearing down the process in the task manager - or even restarting windows, if nothing helps). But it never ever run with `fit` / `fdescribe`, actually.

P.p.s.: My working-mate has no problems with the same project on his dev-machine...

P.p.p.s.: Updated to chrome driver version `2.42` - the error message changed:
`E/launcher - WebDriverError: unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist`

Comment: could you add entire `describe()`?

Comment: there are many tests/files. seems to be in general unstable in my case, see edit in my original post.

Comment: you use `direct` connection, so protractor uses chrome that installed on your machine. So, yes - it could be your local issue. I even see the same when you don't have enough space on your system disk.